# Processing:Transparent Image Array

Tags: arrays, processing, transparent, pgraphics

I'm new to processing and I got stuck on this:

Aim: I want to make an array of transparent images, shown one at a time after each mousePressed ()

Problem: What happens is due to the fact that there is an alpha transparency on all images, they overlap and there is a cumulative effect. What I want to do, ideally is to clear it and then show another image.

```java
PGraphics pg;
PImage[] 
myImageArray = new PImage[12];

void setup() {
  //background (255,0);
  size(1024, 1024,P2D);

 for (int i=0; i<myImageArray.length; i++) {
    myImageArray[i] = loadImage( "A-0" + i + ".png");
    pg = createGraphics (1000,1000);
  }
}

void draw() {
 pg.beginDraw (); 
 pg.image(myImageArray[(int)random(12)], 0, 0, 1000, 1000);
 pg.endDraw ();

 image(pg,0,0); 
 noLoop ();
}
void mousePressed() {

  pg = createGraphics(1000,1000);
 if (frameCount > 1) {
  pg.beginDraw ();
  pg.clear();
  pg.endDraw ();
loop ();

  }

}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're just looking for the `background()` function. The `background()` function clears out old frames by drawing a solid color as the background.

You can find more info in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/background_.html).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! As you said, the background () function fills it with a solid color, which I am trying to avoid so as to preserve the alpha transparency. That's why I'm using PGraphics, as opposed to just PImage.

Comment: @K___S The window itself isn't transparent, is it? Call the `background()` function inside the `draw()` function to redraw the window background to clear out old frames.

Comment: Hey Kevin, thanks so much! My confusion came from the fact that I thought if I call background (); in draw() it would save with the background, but it didn't.

Comment: @K___S What do you mean by saving with the background?

Comment: I thought if I called `background (255);` in `draw();` and call `pg.save ();` it would save the .png with the called background color. Does that make sense?

Comment: @K___S Ohh I see. That makes sense, but that's not what will happen. As long as you're calling `pg.save()`, only what you drew to `pg` will be saved. If you wanted to save what's shown on the screen, then you could call `save()` or `saveFrame()` without the `pg` variable.

Comment: @K__S please do not forget to give the green mark if Kevin Workman answered your question.